# Receiving #Error when using IIF() to show Month Name from Int or Year Int

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my query I am summing data to show Month totals for the current year, and year totals for YTD and previous two years.  I have one column that contains the number of the month for the month totals, and the number of the year for the year totals.

[image]

I have the following expression in a table cell to show either the name of the month or the year as a category:

```
=IIF(Fields!MonthInt.Value < 1000, Left(MonthName(Fields!MonthInt.Value),3), Fields!MonthInt.Value)
```

It works as it should for the names of the months, but the years are showing #Error.

[image: Snip of table showing error]

I assumed it was due to the month names being converted to a string, and the Years remaining an Integer.  To fix this I used CStr() and Str() to convert the year to a string, but this did not work.  I also tried some custom code I found and tried to change to what I need, but I don't know VB well enough to trouble shoot the error I got from that.

Are there any other tricks for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Your IIF statement will not work as it will always evaluate both the true and false parts. When the MonthInt field only contains a month, the LEFT function will fail as it tries to return 3 characters but there will never be more than two.

By Using SWITCH and changing the order of the expressions you can avoid this. SWITCH stops at the first expression that is true.

The following code should work.

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!MonthInt.Value > 1000, Fields!MonthInt.Value,
        True, Left(MonthName(Fields!MonthInt.Value),3)
        )
```

Added **working** solution.
I had been under the misconception (for years) that SWITCH stopped at the first true result. Apparently this is not the case when you mix datatypes. The issue was that the MonthName function expects a value between 1 and 12 so for the year rows, it was trying to pass 2018 to the function. To get round this, I now pass in an IIF statement which passes a dummy value of 1 if the MonthID field is greater than 12.

I've tested this (finally) and it does work as expected.

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!MonthInt.Value > 1000, Cstr(Fields!MonthInt.Value) ,
        Fields!MonthInt.Value < 1000, Left(Cstr(MonthName(IIF(Fields!MonthInt.Value<=12,Fields!MonthInt.Value,1))),3)
        )
```

Comment: This did not work at all.  Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.  Removing the 'True' from your code allowed the report to run, but now all columns show #ERROR

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, I had missed a comma at the end of the second line. I've edited the answer.

Comment: This allowed the Month names to come through, but still showing #Error for the years.  For now I have solved this by changing the query.  Posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I finally got to test this and found a solution although it's not elegant. I updated the answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

> =IIF(Fields!MonthInt.Value < 1000, Left(MonthName(Fields!MonthInt.Value),3), Fields!MonthInt.Value)

Above query might be showing error due to the conversion, try below code

```
> =IIF(Fields!MonthInt.Value < 1000, CStr(Left(MonthName(Fields!MonthInt.Value),3)),
> CStr(Fields!MonthInt.Value))
```

Comment: This did not work either.  Still showing #Error for the year columns.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by changing the query up a bit.  I used the datename() function to get the name of the months, and converted the years to nvarchar.  Due to this change I had to alter some other features in the report, so it was not ideal, but was able to get it worked out in the end.

I am still open to other answers for future reference.